# How do I reuse a component and change some values like text and images in another component using React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to coding and React so please bear with me.

I created a component which I plan on using on a lot of different components. It currently looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Feature = () => (
    <div>
        <div>{this.title}</div>    
        <div><img src={this.img}/></div>
    </div>
);

export default Feature;
```

Now, I would like to change the title and image in this page:

```
import React from 'react';
import Feature from './Feature';

const bacon = {
    title: "bacon",
    img: "./img/sample.jpg"
};

const burger = (props) => (
    <div className="wrapper">       
        <Feature title={bacon.title} img={bacon.img}/>
    </div>
);

export default burger;
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just use [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for this purpose:

```
import React from 'react';

const Feature = (props) => (
    <div>
        <div>{props.title}</div>    
        <div><img src={props.img}/></div>
    </div>
);

export default Feature;
```

The second component is the same

```
const bacon = {
    title: "bacon",
    img: "./img/sample.jpg"
};

const burger = (props) => (
    <div className="wrapper">       
        <Feature title={bacon.title} img={bacon.img}/>
    </div>
);

export default burger;
```